# Transactions in Drupal 6

Tags: 6, database

I am running drupal 6.22 with MySQL. There is no drupal 6 API for using transactions. Since I am new to drupal, I do not know which is the best way to use transactions using the existing drupal APIs? Can anyone guide me on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Transactions are done with SQL and in Drupal 6 you need to write all your SQL. So to use transactions, all you need to do, is to use `db_query(SQL)` and include transaction in the SQL you create.

This could look like this:

```
$sql = 'START TRANSACTION;
       SELECT @A:=SUM(salary) FROM table1 WHERE type=1;
       UPDATE table2 SET summary=@A WHERE type=1;
       COMMIT;';
db_query($sql);
```

Remember to use an engine that supports transactions like `innodb`.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually initiate a transaction with a db_query() run many db_query()'s and then either do a commit or rollback with another db_query() as in:

```
// start transaction
db_query("START TRANSACTION");

// repeat the following as required
db_query("SELECT ...");
db_query("UPDATE ...");

// end transaction
db_query("COMMIT");  - or -  db_query("ROLLBACK");
```

With this be very careful, you cannot return in the middle of your function without first making sure that you do a COMMIT or ROLLBACK. The safest way to do that is to create a transaction object and use RAII (i.e. the destuctor of that object makes sure one of COMMIT or ROLLBACK is sent).